# How to retrieve absolute urls to thumbnails generated via django-filer easy-thumbnails

Tags: django, easy-thumbnails, django-filer

I am using following template tags to display thumbnails in my templates

```
{% load thumbnail %}
{% thumbnail obj.image 250x250 crop %}
```

thumbnail template tag returns relative urls to thumbnail image files as expected. But I would like it to return absolute urls. Normally easy-thumbnails has THUMBNAIL_MEDIA_URL = '' setting which allows thumbnail's storage to build absolute urls but it does not work with django-filer.

Is there any other way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the thumbnail properties using `as`

```
{% thumbnail obj.image 250x250 as thumb %}
{{thumb.url}}
```

See http://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/#thumbnail-tag

EDIT:

If by "absolute" you mean including the website, I would recommend doing the logic elsewhere.

Considering `image` to be a `FilerImageField`, create a property in the `models.py`. Example:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from easy_thumbnails.files import get_thumbnailer

@property
def thumbnail_absolute_url(self):
    if self.image:
        thumbnailer_options = {'size': (250, 250), 'crop': True}
        thumb = get_thumbnailer(self.image).get_thumbnail(thumbnailer_options)
        thumb_url = thumb.url
        site = Site.objects.get_current()
        return site.domain + thumb_url
    return None
```

See https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails#manually-specifying-size--options